# Converting list from lapply to data frame

Tags: r

I'm  having trouble converting my lists from lapply to a data frame. My final output, xx, is close to what I'm looking for, but not exactly. Right now it's 2 observations of 10 variables. Each observation is a list of 280, but I'd like my final data frame to be 560 observations of 10 variables, so just the lists expanded and stacked on one another. I appreciate any help.

```
cid_station=data.frame(cid=1:280,station=sample(1:10,size=280,replace=T))

cid=unique(cid_station$cid)

july = rbind(cid_station[rep(1:280,450),])
july$resid=rnorm(n=nrow(july))

w1=data.frame(station=sample(1:10,size=2400,replace=T),
                   kwhhat=rnorm(n=2400,mean=50,sd=10), year=1)
w2=data.frame(station=sample(1:10,size=2400,replace=T),
              kwhhat=rnorm(n=2400,mean=500,sd=10), year=2)
weather= rbind(w1,w2)

iteration=(1:10)
year=(1:2)


x=lapply(iteration,function(z){

  i=lapply(year,function(yr){
    subset_y=weather[weather$year==yr,]

      peaks=lapply(cid,function(id){
            subset_r=july[july$cid==id,"resid"]
            subset_s=unique(july[july$cid==id,"station"])
            subset_w=subset_y[subset_y$station==subset_s,]
            subset_w$resid=sample(subset_r,size=nrow(subset_w),replace=T)
            subset_w$kw=subset_w$kwhhat+subset_w$resid
            peak=max(subset_w$kw)
          })
      })
  })

xx=as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there must be some optimization possible in your code, but I'm not clear enough on what you're trying to do.  That said -  the `map_dfc` function in the `purrr` package should get you exactly what you want.

```
xx <- map_dfc(x, unlist)
```

Comment: `map_dfc(x, unlist)` will do just as fine.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting the following error?  "Error in cbind_all(x) : Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL]"

Comment: @hpesoj626 you are correct - that was a legacy from more complicated previous attempts.  I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: @mjs1295 - not without more information.  is the code you sent exactly what you are running, or are you simplifying/replacing things?  could your actual data contain missing or unbalanced blocks which would cause problems?.